# Perform a wald's test to check the statistical significance of biasedness of MLE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, unbiased-estimator

I have done a simulation to see that MLEs are asymptotically unbiased. I want to know whether I can perform a wald test here to check the statistical significance of the difference between the mean of parameter estimates (for a given sample size) and true value. If so, do I have to work out the sample variance of the parameter estimates or fisher's information matrix?

Comment: A significance will tell you nothing useful in this case. The probability of rejecting the null (a null you know to be false if there's small-sample bias) is determined by your chosen sample size; so you can make it as large as you like.

Comment: @Glen_b When the sample size is small, doesn't it reject the null hypothesis implying that there is a difference between the mean of parameter estimates and the true value (i.e., biasedness of MLE in finite sample size)? But when sample size is large enough, the test will not reject H0

Comment: Replicate the simulation as much as possible (10,000). Get simple 50% CI. If CI is very narrow and still cover the true value of the parameter, you can say it is nearly unbiased.

Comment: @shani Sorry to be unclear -- the bias is determined by the size of the sample ($n$) but the *power* will also be impacted by the size of your simulation ($n_\text{sim}$). You can choose any simulation size, ergo, you can always detect the bias if you choose to, or fail to detect it if you choose not to. Almost all ML estimators are biased (we tend to study a few convenient cases which lets us see unbiased ones but that's not typical more generally). Having 0 bias usually matters much less to me than (say) having good mean square error. Calculate or estimate bias by all means; but testing it?

Comment: @a_statistician "as much as possible" would seem to be more than 10000 simulations in typical situations. I frequently do simulations in the millions or tens of millions on a laptop with quite modest specs.

Comment: Maybe you are computer us fasterr than mine. In addition, I did this kind of thing years ago.

Comment: It's possible you may be considering more complex simulations. In any case we already *know* it's biased (the thing a significance test will try to tell us). A useful question might be "how much" or "does it matter", either of which is not a question of significance.

Comment: Another consideration is: The number of pseudo random number is limited. If continuing the replication, is it possible that 100001th dataset is exact the same as the 1st dataset?

Comment: The probability of getting statistical *significance* is determined by an arbitrary number (the simulation size) you're choosing based on convenience, to answer a question you already know the answer to. What are we learning? Only whether we did enough simulations to detect it.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. I agree with you that having a good mean squared error is important. However, to explain the intuition of asymptotic unbiasedness of MLEs in an experimental setting, is there a better way to do so. The whole point of using hypothesis testing was to explain this asymptotic unbiasedness in simple terms. Plotting biasedness with sample size conveys some idea, but can we do more than this?

Comment: Sure, but it depends on what you want to know. Note that for many estimators, bias will vary in proportion to a simple power of $n$ (e.g. $n^{-1}$), or is asymptotically of such a form. If you have a good idea of that power and the constant out the front, it pretty much tells you everything about bias in largish samples.

Comment: @Glen_b: I am considering parameters of an AR(2) process. I haven't come across any results relevant to this other than numerical optimization. If you know any reference that would be great.

Comment: The complete-data likelihood is not linear in the parameters, so optimization is generally what is done. You're after references on bias in AR estimation? I believe the bias is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ (while the standard error is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-\frac12})$), so in sufficiently large samples the bias will be small relative to the standard error. It might be worth a post seeking references (no doubt I could turn some up but others will likely have better references).